# Save MATLAB figure with different background color

Tags: matlab, printing, figure, save-as

I want to print a MATLAB figure with a dark background and white labels. If I use the `print` or `saveas` command I lose somehow the colors. The plot symbols are dark again and the background is white.

```
points = rand(100,3);
plot3(points(:,1),points(:,2),points(:,3),'*w')
grid on
set(gca,'Color',[0.5 0.5 0.5])
saveas(gcf,'test1','pdf')
saveas(gcf,'test2','png')
print(gcf,'test3.pdf','-dpdf')
```

All three test files end up being wrong. If I choose "Save As" in the figure menu I am able to save the figure correctly.

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To keep the background as in your figure, use the command set.

> set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');

For adjusting the figure in other ways, check out this link

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-84337.html