# Matlab didn't save background color correctly

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to save the figure with a black background. But Matlab was only able to print it in white. I notice a similar question here:

[Save MATLAB figure with different background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886195/save-matlab-figure-with-different-background-color)

But this does not solve my issue. My code is like this:

```
scatter3(randn(1000,1),randn(1000,1),randn(1000,1))
set(gca,'color','k')
set(gcf,'color','k')
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

I got my axis region black but the background is still white. Can you guys help me out?

I am using Matlab 2013a, if this matters. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you saving the figure?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I use `saveas` and now it works! Used to save by hand but failed... Why so different?

Comment: You're probably just not ticking the right box somewhere when saving by hand

Comment: Which box? I just click the save button and choose the format (eps) to save it. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: There are many many settings in the export dialogue box which I think controls what happens when you choose save like you are describing. But anyway, it's easier to do it in code and it works so I wouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dan for helping me on this problem. I write this basically because someone might not read the comments...

You can use `saveas` command to get your figures. That will solve the background issue.